# Filtering list of apps in custom baseadapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter, searchview

I am trying to implement a searchview for my listview of my installed apps with my baseadapter class.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I hit it crashes with

```
09-02 19:56:47.925    1628-1628/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.dev E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.dev, PID: 1628
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.BlockActivity$2.onQueryTextSubmit(BlockActivity.java:126)
```

because I'm not sure how set up my listview and adapter

Currently this is my fragment class:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;





/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 6/17/14.
 */
public  class BlockActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
     ApkAdapter mAppAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> hanadapter;

    SearchManager searchManager;
    SearchView searchView;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Installed Apps"};

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Light_appalled);


        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("GetDisciplined");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "roboto-lightitalic.ttf.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.block_apps);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        final ActionBar finalActionBar = actionBar;
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                finalActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();



        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (!isLoading()) {
                    mAppAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                }
                return true;
            }

            private boolean isLoading() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (!isLoading()) {
                    if (newText.contains(newText)) {
                        mAppAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Here is my BaseAdapter class pay attention to the bottom:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Filter;
import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

//

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    //Pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/LGRicg4U , http://pastebin.com/c4WfmhMK , http://pastebin.com/gFuuM4dY, http://pastebin.com/4Q7EP9G4
    // http://pastebin.com/Te2g072w,  http://pastebin.com/NLT5iUiA ,

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsapp;

    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    TextView appnamestyle;

    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    HashSet checked;
    Filter mFilter;

    String PACKAGE_NAME;

    TextView appname;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];






    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
        TextView packageName;



    }




    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.apkName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/raleway-medium.otf"));

            holder.ck1= (CheckBox)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.packageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_package);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }









        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);



        // Make sure to define it again!
        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;


        final String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        //holder.packageName.setText(PACKAGE_NAME);


        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);


        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);




        // CHANGE UP EVERYTHING! MAKE THIS SHIT WORK, TIGGA!





        checked = new HashSet();

            PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;
            //Log.d("just here: ", PACKAGE_NAME);

            sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPrefsapp = context.getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);





        holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME,false));







        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editorapp = context.getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {

                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, true);
                    editorapp.putString(packageInfo.packageName, packageInfo.packageName);



                    editor.apply();
                    editorapp.apply();

                   // sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, false);
                    editorapp.remove(packageInfo.packageName);


                    editor.apply();
                    editorapp.apply();
                    //sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);




                }

            }



        });





        return convertView;

    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemsFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemsFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<PackageInfo> packageList_2 = packageList;
            String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<PackageInfo> FilteredList = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                results.values = packageList_2;
                results.count = packageList_2.size();
                return results;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < packageList_2.size(); i++) {
                String filterText = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                try {
                    PackageInfo data = packageList_2.get(i);
                    if (data.applicationInfo
                            .loadLabel(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager())
                            .toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)) {
                        FilteredList.add(data);
                    } else if (data.packageName.contains(filterText)) {
                        FilteredList.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            "exception e" + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            results.values = FilteredList;
            results.count = FilteredList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"result-0 "+results.count,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            packageList = (List<PackageInfo>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

How would I set up mAppAdapter to make it filter the results? Have been doing a lot of research but can't produce a solution for my case.

EDIT:

Got this error:

```
Process: com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.dev, PID: 1317
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.dev/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledAppActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my new code:

http://pastebin.com/sGd15Uve

This is my edittext where it says it's null:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutsearch"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/white" />
```

Not sure why this error is being produced when it clearly exists.

Comment: Can you include your xml file with the installed apps list view?

Comment: Sure no problem. my mistake for not including it

Comment: Here you go. Let me know if I can clarify anything else. http://pastebin.com/CbcZEeQQ

Comment: @Hereisthehelpfullink it should  be as simple as this: http://pastebin.com/eb5WxHRQ

Comment: producing alot of errors when applying this to my fragment. can you explain the code a bit? Thanks pskin

Comment: What line in the fragment is that NPE crash occurring at?

Comment: @Hereisthehelpfullink this is a complete working Activity,  what's unclear,  its just ~70 lines of code after all?

Comment: got alot of errors in my fragment so just ended up converting it to a actionbaractivity. Anyways my error is at         EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.layoutsearch);
        et.addTextChangedListener(this);

Comment: just add a layout that has vertical LinearLayout with EditText on the top and ListView below, just like this: http://pastebin.com/sCE9v4US

Comment: Aight I did that and I still got the error. Same line.         et.addTextChangedListener(this);

Comment: take my activity and just run it,  if it works,  modify it to meet your needs

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sGd15Uve

Comment: and my activity is not compiling/not working?

Comment: Well I am still getting the null pointer exception at         et.addTextChangedListener(this);

Comment: I appreciate the help. Hopefully the code will work for me not sure why I am getting this error. I am not sure why it is null

Answer (score 2):

--

EDIT: I've developed a component which lets you filter custom ListViews and change filters dynamically etc.  I think it has an easy implementation and you. Give it a try!

I hope this would be nicer for all of you.

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidFilterableList

--

The easiest way for me:

1. Define custom generic filter
2. Define listeners required to make it generic
3. Link all items to the view

Example:

1. My extends baseAdapter implements the two interfaces
   (IFilteredItem and IFilteredListListener.

Its content is:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements IFilteredListListener<PointOfInterest>, IFilterableItem<PointOfInterest> {    
public MenuListAdapter(Context context,List<PointsOfInterest> points) {
        this.context = context;
        //Elements for the list
        this.points = points;
    }
....
```

BaseAdapter methods, and the other implementations:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return points.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return points.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new ListFilter<PointOfInterest>(points, this, this,this);
    }
    return filter;
}

@Override
public void onSearchResult(List<PointOfInterest> objects) {
    if (objects.size() == 0) {
        points = objects;
        objects.add(mockedPointForEmptyList);
    } else {
        points = objects;
    }
}

@Override
public String getStringForFilter(PointOfInterest item) {
    return item.getTitle();
}
....
```

In my activity, I have a list view. I set my custom adapter, and it will compare an filter by the title of the point of interest:

In your activity, get the edit text which will be used to filter the list, and add the watcher:

```
filterText = (EditText) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

In your activity (attribute zone), define your watcher:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        yourMenuAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};
```

I recommend you to use my own implementation of filter (copy and paste and let me know if you find any mistakes please!):

```
public class ListFilter<T> extends Filter {

private List<T> adapterFilterElements;
private List<T> originalFilterElements;
private final Object mLock = new Object();

private List<String> originalFilterValues;
private IFilteredListListener<T> listener;
private BaseAdapter baseAdapter;
private IFilterableItem<T> filterableItem;

public ListFilter(List<T> originalElements, BaseAdapter baseAdapter, IFilteredListListener<T> listener, IFilterableItem<T> filterableItem) {
    this.adapterFilterElements = originalElements;
    this.originalFilterElements = originalElements;
    this.baseAdapter = baseAdapter;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.filterableItem = filterableItem;
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
    if (originalFilterValues == null) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            originalFilterValues = fillListNamesFromItems(adapterFilterElements);
        }
    }
    if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
        ArrayList<String> list;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>(originalFilterValues);
        }
        results.values = list;
        results.count = list.size();
    } else {
        String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
        ArrayList<String> values;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            values = new ArrayList<String>(originalFilterValues);
        }
        final int count = values.size();
        final ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final String value = values.get(i);
            final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
            // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
            if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                newValues.add(value);
            } else {
                final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                final int wordCount = words.length;
                // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with
                // space(s)
                for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                    if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = newValues;
        results.count = newValues.size();
    }
    return results;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    results.values = fillItemListFromNames((List<String>) results.values);
    listener.onSearchResult((List<T>) results.values);
    adapterFilterElements = (List<T>) results.values;
    if (results.count > 0) {
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}

private List<T> fillItemListFromNames(List<String> names) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>();
    if (names != null) {
        for (String s : names) {
            for (T p : originalFilterElements) {
                if (filterableItem.getStringForFilter(p).equals(s)) {
                    ret.add(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private List<String> fillListNamesFromItems(List<T> items) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (items != null) {
        for (T item : items) {
            ret.add(filterableItem.getStringForFilter(item));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

The constructor receives a base adapter and two implementations of these custom interfaces:

```
public interface IFilteredListListener<T> extends Filterable {
public void onSearchResult(List<T> objects);
```

}

And

```
public interface IFilterableItem<T> {
public String getStringForFilter(T item);
```

}

Hope this concrete example helps!!

Comment: So I should scrap what I currently have?

Comment: Where to I put this? Im kinda confused...more explanation would be well appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer with a concrete example. I think it would be easier for you to understand what I'm trying to explain. Change PointOfInterest for your PackageInfo... this is generic. You only have to reimplement transformations and some stuff to adapt it. I will make a github project, but I don't actually know when this would be possible to me..

Comment: so is MenuListAdapter supposed to be ApkAdapter in my case?

Comment: also I should change PointOfInterest to packageInfo? that produces some errors? But you saw my ApkAdapter methods right? changing them would result in the listview not being showed

Comment: First answer: yes. Second: Have you worked with generic types in Java? You should implement IFilteredListListener<PackageInfo> in your case (and all changes of this kind). The method in charge of loading your views is getView method and you don't have to change it, so you shouldn't have any problem with it

Comment: The others methods, adapt them to your convinience... I'm not just implementing you the class... this is more than this!!!

Please, look that your "packageList" it's the same than my "points"

Comment: Where? please be more specific. I have whole sample running without problems.

Comment: public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements IFilteredListListener<PackageInfo>, IFilterableItem<PackageInfo> {

Comment: I am not sure why that is occuring

Comment: I am checking the code again and it seems correct without these errors. Please, check your imports etc. I would be glad of helping you tomorrow asap, sorry.

Comment: I had to import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter.IFilteredListListener;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter.IFilterableItem;

Comment: Is there anything wrong with that? Here is the full code. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JH6wVMwY

Comment: Defining these methods is required, I give you an example:

    public String getStringForFilter(PackageInfo item) {
        return item.getPackageName();
    }

    public void onSearchResult(List<PackageInfo> objects) {
        this.packageList=objects;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
           filter = new ListFilter<PackageInfo>(packageList, this,     this,this);
      }
      return filter;
    }

Comment: I hope that the component I've developed would be a nicer answer. ;). I've edited the answer. Good luck!