# how to add text changed listener on Edit text in fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

### In my fragment class having customized listview.I have also one     edit  text in it to filter list records on text changed. but some how i am unable to implement it in fragmnet

```
here is my code :
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    llMain = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llMain); 
    llMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    InputSearch=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.search);
    InputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);// Error on this line: create method getFilter() in customadapter

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
 {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @anjali when i put this line  "adapter.getFilter().filter(s);" i am getiing error  which says to create getFilter() method in my custom adapter.

Comment: can anybody tell me hoe to do this in fragment class

Comment: @User_B Are you using custom adapter??

Comment: @User_B Have you done or not still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line`adapter.getFilter().filter(s);` to `MyActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);`

Comment: adapter is object of my CustomAdpater class which extends BaseAdapter. so in this case what to do

Comment: Have you implement Filterable interface in yorr adapter class? Please go through this link : http://codetheory.in/android-filters/ ; http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: its working but now problem is that when i type one letter suppose it is 'a' then all name gets display on the list which contains letter 'a'

Comment: Then it's a solution :-)

Comment: yes its working but i want only those names which starts from the letter i typed .it displays all names which contains 'a'. like if i typed 'anj' then i only want to display name starts from 'anj' instead of 'xyzanj'.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement Filterable for CustomAdapter and ovverride getFilter() method.

```
public CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable 
{
     //override all adapter methods

     @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        // your code here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @User_B Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631382/filtering-list-of-apps-in-custom-baseadapter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android